# Как на основе одного DataFrame сделать выборку из второго DataFrame , чтобы построить третий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, статистика

У меня есть DataFrame, который содержит ссылки на строки в другом DataFrame в формате списка.

Мне нужно собрать новый датафрейм из указанных строк и добавить еще к ним новый столбец суммирующий значения первого DataFrame.

Чтобы было понятнее, сделал схему. Мне нужно собрать DataFrame как на схеме самый нижний.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
# DataFrame c данными
data = {
    'apples': [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 4, 2, 1], 
    'oranges': [3, 0, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 2],
    'tomat': [1, 1, 4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 7, 2]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# DataFrame c указанием номеров строк в первом
maps = {
    'cat': [3, 0, 4],
    'sklad': [1, 5, 2],
    'vec': [[3, 2, 1], [4, 0], [1, 5, 3, 2]] 
}
dfv = pd.DataFrame(maps)
```

Я начал делать все через циклы и условия и понимаю, что это сильно избыточно и неустойчиво. Подскажите, как правильно в Pandas выбирать вектора на основе списков и добавлять еще вычисляемые значения?

Comment: можете привести выходной DF в виде текста или в виде кода (как `df` или `dfv` в вопросе)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [функцией `explode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/5741205):

```
In [21]: t = explode(dfv, 'vec')

In [22]: t
Out[22]:
   cat  sklad  vec
0    3      1    3
1    3      1    2
2    3      1    1
3    0      5    4
4    0      5    0
5    4      2    1
6    4      2    5
7    4      2    3
8    4      2    2

In [23]: res = df.loc[t['vec']]

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
   apples  oranges  tomat
3       4        2      2
2       1        4      4
1       2        0      1
4       5        1      8
0       3        3      1
1       2        0      1
5       0        2      6
3       4        2      2
2       1        4      4
```

---

> Нужно добавить к датафрейму "res" столбцы "cat" и "sklad".

```
In [50]: res = df.loc[t['vec']].join(t.drop('vec', axis=1))

In [51]: res
Out[51]:
   apples  oranges  tomat  cat  sklad
0       3        3      1    3      1
1       2        0      1    3      1
1       2        0      1    3      1
2       1        4      4    3      1
2       1        4      4    3      1
3       4        2      2    0      5
3       4        2      2    0      5
4       5        1      8    0      5
5       0        2      6    4      2
```

Comment: Есть еще вторая часть вопроса. Нужно добавить к датафрейму "res"  столбцы "cat" и "sklad".  Я пробовал вот так res = df.loc[t['vec', 'cat',  'sklad']] но получаю ошибку KeyError: ('vec', 'cat',  'sklad'). Как правильно добавить столбцы?